# Declaring static and non-static variables inside loops

Tags: c++

I want to use a variable inside a loop, but I don't want it to be re-declared on every iteration. Obviously I can declare it outside of the loop but I wondered what would happen if I declared it as *static* inside the loop.

To test this I declared both a ***static*** and a ***non-static*** variable inside a while loop and printed their memory addresses on each iteration. I expected the address of the *non-static* variable to keep changing and that of the *static* to stay the same.

```
  while (true)
  {
    int var1;
    static int var2;

    cout << &var1 << "\n"
         << &var2 << endl;
  }
```

**Results:** To my surprise the addresses of *both* variables stayed the same.

1. Is this some kind of compiler optimization or was I wrong to assume that re-declaring the *non-static* variable should yield a different address on every iteration? I'm using *gcc 9.3.0* with no optimization flags.
2. Is the *static* variable a good alternative to declaring a *non-static* variable outside of the loop (assuming I won't need it in the outer scope and I'm not concerned that the variable will retain its last value in case the loop is entered again at a later time)?

Comment: Regarding "good alternative": depends on what you need the variable for. How are you going to use it? Do you have anything specific in mind?

Comment: Try putting the shown code inside a different function, and then call it directly from `main` *and* from another function (that is called by `main`). Then you should see a difference.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude The difference is of scope and that the variable will start with its last value when it enters the loop a second time. I get that, but would there be any other concerns?

Comment: Not scope, but *life-time*. Both `var1` and `var2` have the exact same scope. The `static` [*storage duration*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration#Storage_duration) of `var2` means that its life-time will be the whole programs full run-time. [Local `static` variables](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration#Storage_duration) are also guaranteed to be zero-initialized, unless explicitly initialized some other way, and also the initialization (and only initialization) is guaranteed to be thread-safe and happen only once.

Comment: I meant it wouldn't be available outside of the while loop, compared to a non-static variable that's declared outside. Thanks for the detail, didn't know it would be zero-initialized.

Comment: Once you have created local static variable it exists untill the program ends. As result, 1. initialization step is executed one time only, and skipped all other times even if you run the cylce again; 2. local static variable continue to store last set value; 3. memory is allocated for local static variable but at some periods of time the variable is not used;

Comment: @SergeyAleksandrovich Cheers, I get the storage-duration thing. Probably didn't express it well enough in my second question.

Comment: The `static` option is going to add some synchronisation to the code as function `static` objects are guaranteed to only be initialised once in multi-threaded code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The non-static variable gets created and destroyed on each iteration of the loop.

It just so happens that it gets created, every time, on the same memory address.

However, relying on this, and relying on the variable's contents getting preserved across loop iterations will be undefined behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Expecting the compiler to change the address of the local variable is not reasonable: there is only a limited number of possible addresses (2<sup>64</sup>) but your loop is infinite, so the address would have to repeat somehow. And the easiest way to repeat is to repeat immediately.

Regarding whether `static` is good enough - depends on the usage. However, `static` is probably not better than local for most usages, otherwise `static` would be the default behavior.

Answer (score 0):

The `static` variable obviously only gets initialized once so it is perfectly reasonable to expect the address to stay the same.

Now, for the non-static variable. When a variable is declared inside a loop, it will be destroyed before the next iteration of the loop. This means that the memory will be available again the next time the loop runs. Therefore, the variable would likely have the same address.

In fact, the compiler probably **has** to do this because it has no way of knowing how many times the loop will run. Since computers only have finite memory, we cannot allocate a new variable at each iteration.

One way to think about it is that the variable is actually created outside the loop. In fact, some languages (e.g. Pascal) actually require you to declare all variables at the beginning of a function. It's just that declaring variables inside loops reduce the cognitive load a bit which is why most languages support it. But in the end, it all comes down to the same thing.